# How can I use the data retrieved in one function as input parameters to another function?

Tags: vbscript

```
Public Function ReadData_Excel(strPathFile,strSheetName)
  Set objExcel=CreateObject("Excel.Aplication")
  Set objWorkbook=objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathFile)
  Set objWrkSheet=objWorkbook.GetSheet(strSheetName)

  For iRow = 1 to objWrkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Retrieve Parameter values from "iRow" rows and columns A & B
    ParameterValue 1= objWrkSheet.Rows(iRow).Columns(iUserNameCol).Value
    ParameterValue 2= objWrkSheet.Rows(iRow).Columns(iPasswordCol).Value
    ...
    ParameterValue n
  Next

  xlBook.Close
  xlApp.Quit
  Set objWrkSheet = Nothing
  Set objWorkbook = Nothing
  Set objExcel= Nothing 
End Function

Public Function Insert_UserdataFromExceltoGUIFields(ParameterValue 1,ParameterValue 2, ...,ParameterValue n)
  'Parameterization Block:
  With Browser("title:=Welcome: XXX", "index:=0")
    'Step 2
    .WebEdit("YID:=YYY").Set ParameterValue 1   'Parameter 1: YYY
    .WebEdit("ZID:=ZZZ").Set ParameterValue 2   'Parameter 2: ZZZ
    ...
    .WebEdit("AID:=AAA").Set ParameterValue n   'Parameter n: ContactNumber
    .Image("name:=INSERT").Click
  End With
End Function
```

My scenario is that I want to use the data that I retrieved with the function `ReadData_Excel()` should be used as input data/parameters for the function `Insert_UserdataFromExceltoGUIFields()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function abc()
  abc = 1
end function

dim a : a = abc
```

The return value is assigned by setting it to a variable with the name of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `Insert_UserdataFromExceltoGUIFields()` inside the function `ReadData_Excel()` (which is actually a procedure rather than a function, since it doesn't return anything).

```
Public Function ReadData_Excel(strPathFile,strSheetName)
  ...
  Set objWorkbook = Nothing
  Set objExcel= Nothing

  Insert_UserdataFromExceltoGUIFields ParameterValue 1, ParameterValue 2, ...
End Function
```

Otherwise you'll have to change `ReadData_Excel()` so that it actually returns the data you read. To do that you should define an appropriate data structure first, though. For instance you could read the data into a dictionary and return that:

```
Public Function ReadData_Excel(strPathFile,strSheetName)
  ...

  Set data = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For iRow = 1 to objWrkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Retrieve Parameter values from "iRow" rows and columns A & B
    data("XXX") = objWrkSheet.Rows(iRow).Columns(iUserNameCol).Value
    data("ZZZ") = objWrkSheet.Rows(iRow).Columns(iPasswordCol).Value
    ...
    data("ContactNumber") = ...
  Next

  ...

  Set ReadData_Excel = data
End Function

Set xlData = ReadData_Excel("C:\path\to\your.xlsx", "somesheet")
```

This would also simplify the interface of `Insert_UserdataFromExceltoGUIFields()`, because you're passing just one object instead of a boatload of distinct parameters (of course you should replace `data` with a more self-explanatory name):

```
Public Function Insert_UserdataFromExceltoGUIFields(data)
  'Parameterization Block:
  With Browser("title:=Welcome: XXX", "index:=0")
    'Step 2
    .WebEdit("YID:=YYY").Set data("XXX")
    .WebEdit("ZID:=ZZZ").Set data("ZZZ")
    ...
    .WebEdit("AID:=AAA").Set data("ContactNumber")
    .Image("name:=INSERT").Click
  End With
End Function
```

Do **not** give in to the temptation of using global variables for the data read from the file. That would entirely defeat the purpose of encapsulating code in functions.